# Task.Run freezing

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, async-await, c#-5.0

Can anyone educate me why the following freezes after completing the lambda:

```
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return SuperLongMethod();
        })
```

...yet the following works as expected:

```
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return SuperLongMethod();
        }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

It seems the Task.Run in the first version doesn't recognize that the lambda has completed.  I have other examples in my code where I use the first version without issue, so I'm at a loss to understand what the difference is.

For clarity, SuperLongMethod() makes a web service call and does a lot of post-processing of the resultant data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing that further up your call stack you're calling `Task.Wait` or `Task<T>.Result` and thus causing [the deadlock issue I describe on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). You should use `await` instead.

As a side note, `SuperLongMethod` should probably be broken up into a `CallWebServiceAsync` and `DoPostProcessing`, and only the `DoPostProcessing` should be wrapped in a `Task.Run`.

Comment: Your blog essentially says to stay away from awaiting tasks, which is a solution to this confounding deadlock, but the reason I'm using the Task.Run is to efficiently force the processing onto another thread so the GUI remains fluid.  Otherwise, it gets pummeled when the post-processing kicks in.  However, your blog's suggestion to use ConfigureAwait(false) on the Task.Run worked perfectly :)

Comment: I should also add that my second example codeblock actually blocks, so it wasn't the workaround I thought it was

Comment: Actually, my blog post recommends awaiting tasks; it discourages *blocking* on tasks. The fact that `ConfigureAwait` worked indicates to me that your code is still not correct - that further up your call stack you're still blocking on the task returned from that `async` method.

Comment: My GUI directly calls my async function with await.  Inside my function the Task.Run executes and blocks but the GUI remains responsive.  When the Task.Run completes, it then continues because of the ConfigureAwait(false) you suggested, whereas before without it, it would deadlock.  I don't believe this approach is incorrect, unless you feel there's potential for inconsistency.

Comment: I'm still not getting a clear picture of your code, but it does feel like something's wrong (`ConfigureAwait` should not be necessary). If you post your code I'll take a look.